# Rails ActiveRecord date between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I need to query comments made in one day. The field is part of the standard timestamps, is `created_at`. The selected date is coming from a `date_select`.

How can I use `ActiveRecord` to do that?

I need something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2010-02-03 00:00:00' AND '2010-02-03 23:59:59'"
```

Answer (score 483, accepted):

Just a note that the currently accepted answer is deprecated in Rails 3. You should do this instead:

```
Comment.where(:created_at => @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day)
```

Or, if you want to or have to use [pure string conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions), you can do:

```
Comment.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @selected_date.beginning_of_day, @selected_date.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Day.where(:reference_date => 6.months.ago..Time.now) works, thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this create a huge range object?

Comment: @KasperGrubbe if you used the range by itself it would, but Rails just uses the first and last values

Comment: @KasperGrubbe @Dex It is not Rails that does that. The Range class in Ruby only saves the lower and upper bounds. This runs fine in irb: `1..1000000000000` I'm unclear on what you mean by 'using the range by itself'

Comment: +1 We can also make it a scope:

`scope :between, -> (a, b) { where(created_at: a..b) }`

Comment: For today's range: User.where(created_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day).count

Answer (score 61):

I would personally created a scope to make it more readable and re-usable:

In you Comment.rb, you can define a scope:

```
scope :created_between, lambda {|start_date, end_date| where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", start_date, end_date )}
```

Then to query created between:

```
@comment.created_between(1.year.ago, Time.now)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very clean approach...perfect!!

Comment: Back to upvote this answer because I searched for this very issue. Guessed incorrectly at the syntax, assumed `#between?` accepted a range.

Answer (score 49):

Rails 5.1 introduced a new date helper method `all_day`, see: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24930

```
>> Date.today.all_day
=> Wed, 26 Jul 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Wed, 26 Jul 2017 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

If you are using Rails 5.1, the query would look like:

```rb
Comment.where(created_at: @selected_date.all_day)
```

Comment: Glorious. This is actually part of the ActiveSupport gem (and subsequently the entire ActiveRecord ecosystem), so it works outside Rails too! Just `require 'active_record'` and you're all set!

Answer (score 27):

This code should work for you:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day})
```

For more info have a look at [Time calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html)

**Note:** This code is [deprecated](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface). Use the code from the answer if you are using Rails 3.1/3.2

Comment: Ok but from the form I get this: {"written_at(4i)"=>"18", "written_at(5i)"=>"56", "content"=>"rrrrrr", "written_at(1i)"=>"2010", "written_at(2i)"=>"5", "written_at(3i)"=>"4"}

How can I build an object to use beginning_of_day?

Comment: This is what I need: http://purab.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/deconstructing-date_select-in-rails/

Comment: I like this method over the accepted answer because it doesn't rely on a db-level `date()` function; it's potentially more db independent.

Answer (score 11):

I ran this code to see if the checked answer worked, and had to try swapping around the dates to get it right. This worked--

```
Day.where(:reference_date => 3.months.ago..Time.now).count
#=> 721
```

If you're thinking the output should have been 36, consider this, Sir, how many days is 3 days to 3 people?

Answer (score 7):

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions =>["date(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? ", '2011-11-01','2011-11-15'])
```

Answer (score 5):

there are several ways. You can use this method:

```
start = @selected_date.beginning_of_day
end = @selected_date.end_of_day
@comments = Comment.where("DATE(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end)
```

Or this:

```
@comments = Comment.where(:created_at => @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been using the 3 dots, instead of 2.  Three dots gives you a range that is open at the beginning and closed at the end, so if you do 2 queries for subsequent ranges, you can't get the same row back in both.

```
2.2.2 :003 > Comment.where(updated_at: 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day..1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2015-07-12 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-07-13 00:00:00.000000')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
2.2.2 :004 > Comment.where(updated_at: 2.days.ago.beginning_of_day...1.day.ago.beginning_of_day)
Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."updated_at" >= '2015-07-12 00:00:00.000000' AND "comments"."updated_at" < '2015-07-13 00:00:00.000000')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

And, yes, always nice to use a scope!

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to get one day it would be easier this way:

```
Comment.all(:conditions => ["date(created_at) = ?", some_date])
```

Answer (score 4):

There should be a default active record behavior on this I reckon. Querying dates is hard, especially when timezones are involved.

Anyway, I use:

```
  scope :between, ->(start_date=nil, end_date=nil) {
    if start_date && end_date
      where("#{self.table_name}.created_at BETWEEN :start AND :end", start: start_date.beginning_of_day, end: end_date.end_of_day)
    elsif start_date
      where("#{self.table_name}.created_at >= ?", start_date.beginning_of_day)
    elsif end_date
      where("#{self.table_name}.created_at <= ?", end_date.end_of_day)
    else
      all
    end
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use below gem to find the records between dates,

This gem quite easy to use and more clear [By star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) am using this gem and the API more clear and documentation also well explained.

```
Post.between_times(Time.zone.now - 3.hours,  # all posts in last 3 hours
                  Time.zone.now)
```

Here you could pass our field also `Post.by_month("January", field: :updated_at)`

Please see the documentation and try it.