# Rails ActiveRecord - how to fetch records between two dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two date columns - `from_date` and `to_date` in a database table.

Example:

- `from_date`: **2012-09-10**
- `to_date`: **2012-09-30**
- `today`: **2012-09-13**

I need to fetch all records, if `today`'s date is between `from_date` and `to_date`. How do I do that with a SQL query?

If I have loaded the respective record, I can easily decide, if today's date is between `from_date` and `to_date`, but I don't know how to fetch those records straight from the database table.

Comment: I think this question may be helpful: [Rails ActiveRecord date between](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2381825/722783)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
data = ModelName.where("today >= from_date AND today <= to_date")
```

Comment: This answer is actually more general than Paulo's. Paulo's query assumes you have a field (`created_at`in his answer) that you expect to have in-between two dates. What if I want to see if today is between `start_date` and `end_date`? Can't do that with Paulo's answer.

Answer (score 55):

Check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on Range conditions:

```
Client.where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the asked question. He wants to know when a date is between the value of two separate columns, this is where a column is between two dates.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the asked question.

Answer (score 11):

A secure and easy way to do this would be:

```
Model.where(':date BETWEEN from_date AND to_date', date: Date.current)
```

Comment: You can use `"?"` and no need to pass a hash containing the bind values (`Model.where('? BETWEEN from_date AND to_date', Date.current)`). Even shorter, you can rely in the functions your RDBMS offers; `Model.where('DATE_CURRENT BETWEEN from_date AND to_date')` (pg specific).

Comment: I know... I prefer passing a hash because it is easier to understand and reads like a sentence. As for relying on the db for the current date, yeah you could, but then you are making the query in your database timezone, rather than in the timezone of your Rails application / user session.

Answer (score 8):

you can use like this:

```
Data = Model.where("date(now()) between from_date and to_date")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
data = ModelName.find(:all, :conditions => "today >= from_date and today <= to_date")
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
today = Date.today

data = ModelName.where("from_date <= ? AND to_date >= ?", today, today)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use below gem to find the records between dates,

This gem quite easy to use and more clear [By star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) am using this gem and the API more clear and documentation also well explained.

```
ModelName.between_times(Time.zone.now - 3.hours,  # all posts in last 3 hours
                  Time.zone.now)
```

Here you could pass our field also `ModelName.by_month("January", field: :updated_at)`

Please see the documentation and try it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after a long search in google looking for a "rails way" to do a BETWEEN with two date fields and a variable, the most approximate solution I found is creating your own [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to do that.

in your ApplicationRecord write:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :between_fields, -> (value, initial_date, final_date) { 
    where "('#{value}' BETWEEN #{initial_date} AND #{final_date})"
   }

end
```

So now, wherever you need to do a between you can do:

```
@clients = Client.between_fields(params[:date], :start_date, :final_date)
# SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ('2017-02-16 00:00:00' BETWEEN start_date AND final_date)
```

You can combine it with others "where" to do your query as specific as you need.

Comment: A scope is a good way to do this, but using string interpolation is a bad idea for security.
You should not be using the ` #{string}` syntax inside queries, especially when you are passing straight from params!

Comment: This implies a single column to be asked for, whereas the question is clearly stating two columns; `from_date` and `to_date`.

Comment: Don't do this. It allows people to perform SQL injections. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection