# Query for has_many through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Association is

```
class Campaign
  has_many :views_logs
  has_many :users, through: :views_logs
end
```

I want to get all `users` in a `Campaign` within any specific dates etc
meaning, I want to do something like:
 `Campaign.first.users.where(?)`

Now, when I query:

```
Campaign.first.users.all
```

I get list of all users within a certain campaign, but how I can I get only those users which have Campaign between specific date ranges only.

Comment: what is the name of those date columns and in which model they are ?

Comment: I cant understand your question. Kindly ellaborate

Comment: *specific date ranges*, against which columns ? Are they normal created_at/update_at date columns or any custom date columns you have? In which model those columns are available ?

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get all users in a Campaign within any specific dates

[`ActiveRecord Association Extension`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/campaign.rb
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, through: :view_logs do
      def between start_date, end_date
         where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
      end
   end
end

@campaign = Campaign.find x
@users    = @campaign.users.between(Date.today - 2, Date.today.day)
```

--

Update - it seems PGSQL requires a [timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930087/1143732) to evaluate dates:

```
@users = @campaign.users.between(Time.now.midnight - 2.days, Time.now.midnight)
```

The difference being that between [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) & [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html) objects.

Comment: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= integer
LINE 1: ...ogs"."campaign_id" = $1 AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2...

Comment: Can you post the full query after `BETWEEN 2` ? Thanks!

Comment: Query is 
Campaign.first.users.between(Date.today - 2, Date.today.day)

Comment: Thanks - when you posted `RROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= integer LINE 1: ...ogs"."campaign_id" = $1 AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2` -- can you show me the last part of the reponse?

Comment: THanks -
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone <= integer
LINE 1: ...ogs"."campaign_id" = $1 AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2..
                                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "views_logs" ON "users"."id" = "views_logs"."user_id" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "views_logs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "views_logs"."campaign_id" = $1 AND ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-01-30' AND 1)

Comment: Looks like we have to send the values as a [timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25930087/1143732), rather than a string as we have now. Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102342/discussion-between-haseeb-ahmad-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 2):

Simply define a scope in `User` like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Your current code
  scope :during_campaign, -> (start, end) { 
       joins(view_logs: :campaign).where('campaigns.created_at >= ? AND campaigns.created_at <= ?', start, end)
  }

end
```

Then use it:

```
# User from yesterday compaign for eg
User.during_campaign(1.day.ago, Time.now)
```

Make it generic & pretty always!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing:

```
Campaign.first.users.where("campaigns.created_at > #{start_date} AND campaigns.created_at < #{end_date}")
```