# nested queries for has_many :through in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Association of model is

```
class Campaign
  has_many :views_logs
  has_many :users, through: :views_logs
end
```

I want to get only those users of campaign where `views_logs` is created b/w specific dates.

Note: created_at query for `views_logs` not for Users creation

Comment: can you put your user model with association here?

Comment: Which model? kindly ellaborate please

Comment: `user` model already mentioned

Comment: @HaseebAhmad I told you to clarify the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35125607/2767755). But you didn't or couldn't. Due to which, you are now asking the same question again in a separate post. So you can fix it in your first question. Prepare the question first, and then ask here.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sorry but I want to ask the same question there but now I doesnt want to delete it..that's why I post new question

Comment: Association of Cmpaign and Users is through Viewslogs. I want to get only those users of campaigns where the Viewslogs.created_at is b/w specific dates

Comment: I understood the fact. That's why I am asking, before post, make the draft clear as much as you can. Otherwise, someone will guess and answer you which might not be what you really asked. :/

Comment: If you understand question and have any solution please share it :)

Comment: Didn't I just answer this exact question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because already been asked before, but deleted first

Comment: No Sir that's different scenario.I want
Association of Cmpaign and Users is through Viewslogs. I want to get only those users of campaigns where the Viewslogs.created_at is b/w specific dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Campaign.joins(:users).where("views_logs.created_at = ?", my_date)
```

Joining Users like this will perform a SQL `JOIN` on your views_logs then a SQL `JOIN` on your users, which allows you to use a view_logs column in your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: Thanks but with I get Campaigns not Users :/

Comment: Then `Users.joins(:campaigns).where("views_logs.created_at = ?", my_date)`

Comment: You seem to not be very fluent with ActiveRecord queries. I recommend reading this : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Sorry but that's not woirking...it gives me user according to their created_at..
I want Association of Cmpaign and Users is through Viewslogs. I want to get only those users of campaigns where the Viewslogs.created_at is b/w specific dates

Comment: Did you find what you needed in the documentation I linked ?