# Find records with a start and end range covering the time now with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a project dealing with opening hours of a store. I have `Store` and `OpeningHour` models, (`Store` `has_many` `OpeningHour`). The `opening_hours` table has `day`, `start` and `end` fields to store the day that `OpeningHour` record is to apply to, the time the store opens and the time the store closes.

What would be the best way of finding any records where the time range set by `start` and `end` fields covers `Time.now`?

Similar to the below conceptually:
`OpeningHour.where((start..end).cover? Time.now)`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404927/5239030)?

Comment: @iGian Thanks for your response. Yes, very similar to this, however the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404927/5328443) relies on all 3 fields being in the database. In my car, the range boundaries are database fields, but the value to check is a variable.

Comment: Did you try `OpeningHour.where("start <= ? AND end >= ?", Time.now, Time.now)`?

Comment: What type are the `start` and `end` columns declared as? You should also note that `end` is not a good column name for a rails app as `end` is a keyword in ruby. Use `ends_at` instead.

Comment: @max The fields are of the `time` datatype. Thanks for the tip on the keyword. I'll fix that!

Comment: The answer will depend a bit on what database is in use since you need to extract the hours and minutes from the time for the comparison.