# get count of users for previous day week or month in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, I wanted to get count of users that have been created and deleted account in the previous day, week and month in my app.Basically I want to show the users that have been created account in one day`(means from current hour to previous remaining hours)`, one week`(means from current day to previous remaining days)` and one month`(means from current day to previous remaining days)`

and I am trying use below:

```
# Controller
@users = User.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ?", Date.today.at_beginning_of_month])

# View
Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.upto(Date.today).each do |date|
  <%= date %>: <%= @users.select{|u| u.created_at == date }.size %>
end
```

But it gets me count of users for each day in past month.

Comment: http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/02/graphical-representation-of-my-model-data-charts-in-ruby-on-rails-using-highcharts/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between

Comment: but I don't have particular date and time, I want this for one day, from current time`(time.now)` to end where 24 hours is completed, similarly for one week, from current time`(time.now)` to end where one week is completed, and similarly for one month, from current time`(time.now)` to end where one month is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

For example if you want to selecet the Users created in the last hour:

```
  @date_start = DateTime.now
  @date_end = @date_start - 1.hour
  @users = User.where(:created_at => @date_end..@date_start)
```

Comment: I want to get count, so I have add `.count` like this `@users = User.where(:created_at => @date_end..@date_start).count`. But its not get me any result.

Comment: Its not get me any error, but in my view page, at this line `Number of users who registered in last 24 hours: <%= @users %>`, its not show me any count value.

Comment: Can you simply print it out in the console with: `puts @users` ? What is the result?

Comment: Did you create a user in the last hour?

Comment: Its working. Thanks, kindly suggest me, how can I do this for `1 Week` and `1 month`.

Comment: Yes for one week you can keep `@date_start` but you change your `@date_end` to `@date_start - 1.week` same with month simply change it to `@date_end = @date_start - 1.month`. Should work! If you get any errors, simply write back!

Answer (score 1):

let's say first this:

```
@date = DateTime.now - 10.days
@users = User.all(:conditions => ['created_at > ?', @date]) // fetch all users created within last 10 days until now
```

then, group it by date:

```
@days = @users.group_by {|user| user.created_at.to_date }
```

then you should do iteration with those grouped days and print them:

```
@days.each do |day, users|
    <%= day %>: <%= users.size %>
end
```