# Rails way of Where Between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to check for the following condition:

```
lower_limit <= VALUE < upper_limit
```

I can do the above using

```
Model.where("lower_limit <= ? AND upper_limit > ?", value, value)
```

but how do I do the same using ranges ? (..)/(...)

Please note the operators:

The first operator of between is "<=" and second operator is ">". 
Had they been same, I could have used (..) or (...).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord date between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between)

Comment: Lower limit <= Value and upper limit > value, The operators are not like lower_limit < value and upper_limit > value or lower_limit <= value and upper_limit >= value

Comment: What are `lower_limit` and `upper_limit`? Are the columns?

Comment: Yes, you can look at this question for whole picture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442782/chaining-of-conditional-where-clauses-using-rails-active-record

Comment: Why don't you update this question instead of asking a new one? You're allowed to clarify your questions through editing.

Comment: That is a different question. Read completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.where(:count => lower_limit..upper_limit)
```

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the SQL this produces? Do you know what BETWEEN does in SQL? Did notice that the question talks about `lower_limit` and `upper_limit` rather than a single column?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a range in the query, but you can still make use of `BETWEEN`. In MySQL, `BETWEEN` is inclusive. You could write something like:

```
Model.where("? BETWEEN lower_limit AND upper_limit - 1", value)
```

Which would generate SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM models WHERE (37 BETWEEN lower_limit AND upper_limit - 1)
```