# In Ruby how to get current date without the hour / min / second for a SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to do:

```
ItemCheck.where('created_at between ?',today, today + 1.day) # <- from 12:00 midnight -> 12:00 midnight
```

Is there a way to do Time.new and tell it to throw away the hour / min / second values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ActiveRecord date between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do something like this

```
ItemCheck.where(:created_at => @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day)
```

also look at [Rails ActiveRecord date between](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946091/1380867)

Comment: thx, ended up doing it like:  ics=ItemCheck.where('(created_at between ? and ?) and location_id=?',today.beginning_of_day, today.end_of_day, location_id)