# Ruby on Rails - Select records within date range (slow performance)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date

*I know how to find records within a date range, and have seen answers to similar questions. My question is how to reformat my date value from "mm/dd/yy" to a format which can be compared to a date range, all within one query.*

I have a column in my database that contains a date in "mm/dd/yy" format. I am trying to write a query that will select all records within a date range defined by `start_date` and `end_date` variables, which are Ruby `Date` objects.

This is the best I have so far, but it's very slow:

```
date_records = Record.select { |r| ( (r.division == division) && (Date.strptime(r.date, "%m/%d/%y") >= start_date) && (Date.strptime(r.date, "%m/%d/%y") <= end_date) ) }
```

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between    Is there a particular reason why you are using the SQL statement directly, instead of ActiveRecord query helpers?

Comment: No reason... I'm fine using `.where`. My main struggle is getting the date from the "mm/dd/yy" format to compare within the query. This is the best I could do, and it's very slow:   `date_records = Record.select { |r| ( (Date.strptime(r.date, "%m/%d/%y") >= start_date) && (Date.strptime(r.date, "%m/%d/%y") <= end_date) ) }`

Comment: Seems like the first job should be to store these dates as dates, not as strings.

Answer (score -1):

I found that converting my records to JSON before doing the `.select` that parses and compares the dates improved performance vastly (~35s down to ~4s):

`division_records = Record.where(division: division).as_json
         date_range_records = division_records.select { |r| ((start_date..end_date).include? Date.strptime(r["date"], "%m/%d/%y")) }`