# Select object based on date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

Tech specs: ruby 2.1.5p273, Rails 4.2.3.

I have an array of Days that I want to loop through to pick the right Exits (model) that fall within a date range.

- @exits has :start_date and :end_date
- @days is an array of dates like:

  => [Sun, 06 Sep 2015, Sat, 12 Sep 2015, Tue, 15 Sep 2015, Fri, 18 Sep 2015, Sat, 19 Sep 2015, Sun, 20 Sep 2015, Wed, 23 Sep 2015]

I thought something like this would work:

```
@days.each do |day|
  @exits.where(:start_date..:end_date).include?(day)
end
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Range
```

What is the best way to query an object that has a date range (between two fields) by comparing it against a single date? Thanks!

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I've done something like this [answer][1] before.  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between

Comment: use `Exit.where('? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date', date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
@days.each do |day|
  exits = Exit.where('? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date', day)
  # etc.
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @MrYoshiji!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loop over them then you can do:

`Event.where("start_date IN (:days) AND end_date IN (:days)", { days: @days })`

or

`Event.where(start_date: @days, end_date: @days)`

Answer (score -1):

```
Exit.where(day: @exit.start_date..@exits.end_date)

or 

Exit.where('day >= ? AND day <= ?', @exit.start_date, @exits.end_date)
```

Doing SQL queries in a loop is probably a bad idea, it could be refactored to be be one call most likely. And this should happen in the controller not in the view.

Comment: Thanks @penner but is being handled in the controller.