# rails date filter in prepoulated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table already being rendered with a bunch of data, Including dates.

Here is some of the code i have ready for a search.

```
<%= form_for :search, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :start_date, value: @start %>
  <%= f.date_field :end_date, value: @end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

And this is in my controller

```
@start = selected_date(:start_date)
  @end = selected_date(:end_date)
  @eventsdate = params[:search].present? ? Event.where(@start..@end) : Event.none
end

private

def selected_date(symbol)
  params[:search].present? && params[:search][symbol].present? ? params[:search][symbol].to_date : Time.now.to_date
end
```

What I want is a simple date filter. What can i do to get this to work? The table has one column with a bunch of dates in, Basically just need to get the dates within range

The reason why @eventsdate exists is because i was going to have it as a render on search, which is no good as i need the table to exist beforehand for the text search

Comment: I think you'll get an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between

Comment: i was looking into this, then my brain died and i couldnt work out how to actually make it work haha! :(

Comment: you just need to add the column name your filtering : `Event.where(my_date_column: @start..@end)`

Comment: That didnt work, I had tried that before

Comment: Oh that's probably because of what you're feeding it with. Rails is quit clever with dates, it should work without fiddling with the params: try `where(my_date_column: params[:search][:start_date]..params[:search[: end_date])`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']'
...[:start_date]..params[:search[: end_date])
...

Comment: The unexpected is on the '[' just after the params

Comment: oups sorry typo : where(my_date_column: params[:search][:start_date]..params[:search][:end_date])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96366/discussion-between-tester123-and-charlysisto).