# Ruby on Rails: How to query relation objects based on date range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :clicks
 has_many :cpas
 has_many :ftds
 has_many :signups
end
```

and

```
class Click < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Cpa < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Ftd < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Signup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

The models *clicks, cpas, ftds, signups* are kind of events that happens throughout the time to the **campaign** model. I want to create a reports page the list all the campaign and show on each line the events (clicks, cpas, ftds, signups) that happened(created_at) on given time(on this month).

On my attemps I get the campaign with events on the month, but the data listed on the lines brings events that happened on other month I chose, but also others months.

```
def self.filter_by_date(start_date = Time.now.beginning_of_month, end_date = Time.now.end_of_month)
  joins(:clicks).where(clicks: {created_at: start_date..end_date}) +
  joins(:ftds).where(ftds: {created_at: start_date..end_date}) +
  joins(:cpas).where(cpas: {created_at: start_date..end_date}) +
  joins(:signups).where(signups: {created_at: start_date..end_date})
end
```

Sorry for the not so good english, I'm Brazilian.

Comment: Not sure which bit you are stuck on, this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between

Comment: My big problem is more related with the *joins* @TonyHopkinson. But thanks anyway :D

Comment: Maybe you could add your query code showing an example of what doesn't work?

Comment: @MarcRohloff I edited the question, added more info and the code I tried, maybe it helps you help me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho certeza que sua Ingles e melhor do que o meu Portugues. It might help if you showed how you display this data. As you've written it it will get all Campaigns that have clicks, ftds, cpas or signups within the period and then (I assume) display all the clicks, etc for each Campaign. It might also have duplicate campaigns. Depending on what you are trying to do you could:

- Get each type separately an display it:

  ```
  clicks = Clicks.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
  render_clicks(clicks)
  ftds = Ftds.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
  render_ftds(ftds)
  ```
- Write something like:

  ```
  def self.filter_by_date(start_date = Time.now.beginning_of_month, end_date = Time.now.end_of_month)
    condition = {created_at: start_date..end_date}  
    self.includes(:clicks ).where(clicks:  condition)
        .includes(:ftds   ).where(ftds:    condition)
        .includes(:cpas   ).where(cpas:    condition)    
        .includes(:signups).where(signups: condition)
  end
  ```

This would give you all papers but only the clicks, ftds, cpas and signups that were created in between those dates.

- If your goal is to return campaigns with activity between that period then it is possible to write a query to do it, but it would be complex and perform badly. I would add a `last_activity' column to the`campaigns`table of type`datetime`, then change your code as follows:

  ```
  class Click < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :campaign, touch: :last_activity
  end

  class Cpa < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :campaign, touch: :last_activity
  end

  class Ftd < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :campaign, touch: :last_activity
  end

  class Signup < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :campaign, touch: :last_activity
  end

  def self.filter_by_date(start_date = Time.now.beginning_of_month, end_date = Time.now.end_of_month)
    where(last_activity: start_date..end_date)
  end
  ```