# Get Record Created 30 Minutes Ago - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get records created 30 minutes ago from `Time.now`. I'm using a cron and I want to fire the cron once ever minute.

I essentially need this except it should ignore the seconds so that if `Time.now == Wed, 31 Jan 2018 18:00:31 +0000` then a record with `created_at = "Wed, 31 Jan 2018 17:30:23 +0000` should match.

Here is the query I have so far which doesn't work because the time is improperly evaluated.

```
Cart.joins(:cart_addresses).group('carts.id').where(created_at: Time.now - 30.minutes).each do |i|
  puts i.id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below query:

```
# if current time is 3:00:03
# it will return carts created at 2:30:00 -> 2:30:59
from_mins_ago = 30.minutes.ago.change(sec: 0)
to_mins_ago   = from_mins_ago.change(sec: 59) 
Cart.joins(:cart_addresses).group('carts.id').where(created_at: from_mins_ago..to_min_ago).pluck('carts.id')
```

Comment: This query would get everything within the last 30 minutes and not 30 minutes ago, right?

Comment: Previous query is like what you said. But I have just updated the query. Please check the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a range.

`Cart.joins(:cart_addresses).group('carts.id').where(created_at: 30.minutes.ago..DateTime.now)`

There's a lot of solutions.

More: [Rails ActiveRecord date between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between/12946091)