# How to validate range dates with rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

hello i have a post module where the user can select the dates for publishing his posts, i have 2 fields

```
start_date:date and expiration_date:date
```

i want to make a validation like this

if user selects start_date = 2022-10-14 and expiration_date = 2022-10-22, he can't create another post that is between that range.

because i can have only 1 post published at a time, so with this validation i will force the user to select any other date that is not in between this selected range dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that there is no other post that starts before the expiration date and ends after the start date.  Also exclude this post's id in your check in case you're updating an existing post. (The post shouldn't prevent itself from changing).

This will catch posts that overlap the current post completely or partially, or that start and end within the current post.

```
validates :date_range

def date_range
  if user.posts.where.not(id: id).where(start_date: ..expiration_date, expiration_date: start_date..).any?
    errors.add(:start_date, 'there is already a post that overlaps these dates')
  end
end
```

Comment: This is excellent and honestly better than my implementation. Just 2 notes: 1) `<` and `>` should be `<=` and `>=` otherwise there will be overlap. 2) since rails 5 you can use ranges to express these with the Hash interface e.g. `where(start_date: ..expiration_date, expiration_date: start_date..)`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the excellent suggestions, answer now modified.

Answer (score 1):

Inside you `Post` model you'll need a some validation.

You can create a custom method that will check whether the post you're trying to create has a start date between any current post.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  
  validate :post_exists? on: :create


  private

  def post_exists?
    return unless Post.where("? BETWEEN start_date AND expiration_date", self.start_date).present?
  
    errors.add(:start_date, "Post already exists")
  end

end
```

I'm unable to test this at the moment, but its roughly what you'll need.

Some light reading on the on the subject ~ 
Custom validate methods: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods
Validating on certain actions, i.e. `on: :create`: in this case.
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

It's worth mentioning there are some very similar other questions on stack, worth a google.
[Rails ActiveRecord date between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381718/rails-activerecord-date-between)

Comment: Using the [`::exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) method will be much faster and functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you are looking to ensure there are no "overlaps". This entails ensuring all of the following are true

- New `start_date` is not BETWEEN (inclusive) an existing `start_date` and `expiration_date`
- New `expiration_date` is not BETWEEN (inclusive) an existing `start_date` and `expiration_date`
- New `start_date` is not prior to an existing `start_date` and New `expiration_date` is not after the corresponding existing `expiration_date`

To satisfy these rules I would implement as follows:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :start_date, presence: true,comparison: { less_than: :expiration_date}
  validates :expiration_date, presence: true, comparison: { greater_than: :start_date }
  validate :non_overlapping_date_range

  def time_frame 
    start_date..expiration_date
  end 
  
  private 
    def non_overlapping_date_range 
       overlaps_post = Period
         .where(start_date: time_frame )
         .or(Post.where(expiration_date: time_frame ))
         .or(Post.where(start_date: start_date..., expiration_date: ...end_date))
         .where.not(id: id)
         .exists?
      errors.add(:base, "overlaps another Post") if overlaps_post
   end 
end
```

This will result in the following query

```
 SELECT 1 AS one 
 FROM 
  posts 
 WHERE
  ((posts.start_date BETWEEN '####-##-##' AND '####-##-##' 
  OR posts.expiration_date BETWEEN '####-##-##' AND '####-##-##')
  OR (
    posts.start_date > '####-##-##' 
    AND posts.expiration_date < '####-##-##'
  ))
  AND posts.id != # -- IS NOT NULL on create
 LIMIT 1
```

**Using OVERLAPS (Postgres)**

Postgres offers a function called `OVERLAPS` however the this does not fully fit the desired situation because this function treats `end_date == new_start_date` as continuous rather than overlapping. To counteract this we need to adjust the start_date and end_date for the purposes of the query

This can be achieved as follows:

```
def non_overlapping_date_range 
  overlaps_post = Post.where.not(id: id)
                 .where('(?,?) OVERLAPS (posts.start_date, posts.expiration_date)',
                        start_date - 1, end_date + 1))
                 .exists?
errors.add(:base, "overlaps another Post") if overlaps_post

end
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 1 AS one 
 FROM 
  posts 
 WHERE
  ('####-##-##','####-##-##') OVERLAPS (posts.start_date,posts.expiration_date)
  AND posts.id != # -- IS NOT NULL on create
LIMIT 1
```

Arel port of the same:

```
def non_overlapping_date_range 
  left = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    [Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
      'DATE', 
      [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(start_date - 1)]),
    Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
      'DATE', 
      [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(expiration_date + 1)])])
  right = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    [Post.arel_table[:start_date],
     Post.arel_table[:expiration_date]])
  condition = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('OVERLAPS', left, right)
  errors.add(:base, "overlaps another Post") if Post.where.not(id: id).where(condition).exists?
end
```