# Query that checks overlap with composed timeframe (postgres, ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a Schema like this:

```rb
User(:id)
Event(:id, :start_date, :end_date,:duration, :recurrence_pattern)
EventAssignment(:user_id, :event_id, :date)
```

`recurrence_pattern` is a rrule string (see https://icalendar.org/rrule-tool.html, https://github.com/square/ruby-rrule)

`date` is a date formatted like 'YYYY-MM-DD'

`start_date` and `end_date` are timestamps like 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'

I want to find all users that have at least one allocation overlapping with 2 timestamps, say *from* and *to*

So I wrote a bit of postgres and arel

```
assignment_subquery = EventAssignment.joins(:event).where(
    '"user_id" = users.id AND
    (?) <= "event_assignments".date + (to_char("events".start_date, \'HH24:MI\'))::time + make_interval(mins => "events".duration) AND
    (event_assignments.date) + (to_char(events.start_date, \'HH24:MI\'))::time <= (?)',
from, to).arel.exists

User.where(assignment_subquery)
```

edit: some more postgres(@max)

```
assignment_subquery = EventAssignment.joins(:event).where(
'"user_id" = users.id AND
    ("event_assignments".date + (to_char("events".start_date, \'HH24:MI\'))::time + make_interval(mins => "events".duration),
    (event_assignments.date) + (to_char(events.start_date, \'HH24:MI\'))::time) 
 OVERLAPS ((?), (?))'
, from, to).arel.exists
```

Which works fine

my question is:
Is there a <s>better</s> more rails way to do this?

Comment: There is a more Postgres way to do it which is to use the OVERLAPS operator. https://andreigridnev.com/blog/2016-03-30-overlaps-operator-in-postgresql/

Comment: If an event has a "start_date" and an "end_date" (both of which appear to be datetime). I would assume the "date" portion of this would be equal to the EventAssignment date. If that is the case then what need do you have for the duration? Seems like you could just use the start_date and end_date and one of the solutions provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070757/how-to-validate-range-dates-with-rails-6/74071874)

Comment: @engineersmnky no, that's not the case. An event may be, for example, recurring every day at the same time. Then the start_date of the event includes information about the first date of the series as well as the starting time. The end_date contains information about when the series should end(which is already included in recurrence_pattern, but this way queries are easier) Now, since an event can be at most frequent daily, an allocation can be identified by its date, the event and the user that is assigned to the event. A user may be assigned to the same event on multiple days.

Comment: In that case what you have is probably the best you are going to get. "Is there a more rails way?" well I could certainly convert this to Arel but the only reason for that really would be portability and given the DB specific mechanisms here e.g. type casting and/or the use of OVERLAPS the SQL is not really portable. Only comment I have is that I have no idea how `"user_id" = users.id` is working since the User table is not joined here and even so I would recommend qualifying "user_id" e.g. `event_assignments.user_id` in case you join another table with a "user_id" column.

Comment: For the subquery.arel.exists part, I got that from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754820/rails-activerecord-where-exists-query. There, the place isn't joined either. In any case, qualifying which user_id column to check is probably a good idea, thanks @engineersmnky!

Comment: I apologize I overlooked this part `User.where(assignment_subquery)`.